# Why does the following remark on probability space not work on infinite, yet countable, sets?

Tags: probability

I've recently been reading some online material on probability and came across a text at the following link: [https://web.math.princeton.edu/~rvan/acm217/ACM217.pdf](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ervan/acm217/ACM217.pdf)

However, page 27 of the PDF has a remark that doesn't quite make sense to me and I was hoping someone could point out what I'm missing.  It says:

> Let ($\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}$) be a probability space, and let
> {$A_n$} $\subset\mathcal{F}$ be countable.
>
> 1. If $\mathbb{P}$($A_n$) = 0 for all n, then $\mathbb{P}$($\bigcup_nA_n$) = 0.
> 2. If $\mathbb{P}$($A_n$) = 1 for all n, then $\mathbb{P}$($\bigcap_nA_n$) = 1.
>
> In words: if every event $A_n$ has zero probability of happening, then
> with unit probability none of these events happen. If every event
> $A_n$ happens with unit probability, then the probability that all
> these events occur simultaneously is one.
>
> This may seem a tautology, but it is nice to see that our intuition is
> faithfully encoded in the mathematics. More importantly, however, note
> that the statement is not true for uncountable families {$A_n$}. For
> example, under the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, any individual
> outcome {$x$} has zero probability of occurring.  However, the
> probability that one of these outcomes occurs is $\mathbb{P}$($[0,1]$)
> = 1!

I understand why the statements are not true for "uncountable families" {$A_n$}, but the example they used has me wondering about countable sets that are also infinite. In considering something like the set of all rational numbers on $[0,1]$, wouldn't the probability of choosing any single one be equal to $0$ while the probability that one of them occurs overall be equal to $1$, and doesn't that negate everything the text is asserting previously?

Comment: With respect to your proposed counterexample, what is the probability distribution?

Comment: Apologies if this doesn't make much sense - I'm going to be starting grad school soon but have only worked with probability and higher-level math like this in separate classes.  My thought on the probability distribution would be something intuitively like a uniform distribution, though I know based on other posts you can't technically have that on only the reals.  Is there anything that could be considered in this case or is that breakdown in choosing a proper distribution the reason why the remark in the text holds?

Comment: The latter.  Since probability measures are countably additive, if your probability space is countable (such as $[0, 1] \cap \Bbb Q$), it can't be the case that the probability of choosing any single element is always $0$.  That's because the probability measure must sum to $1$.

Comment: So just to make sure I have it clear, the statement in the text has to be true because by virtue of the space being countable, the probability of choosing any single element can't be 0 even though something like your example ($[0, 1] \cap \Bbb Q$) has infinitely many elements?  Only uncountable spaces can have the probability of choosing a single element as 0?

Comment: Not quite.  The sum of the probabilities exists (because the space is countable) and has to be $1$.  That means it can't be the case that *all* of the points have probability $0$.  But any one point can have probability $0$.  In fact, all but one of the points can have probability $0$, forcing the last point to have probability $1$.  In a continuous space, we would use measures such as the Lebesgue measure.  The space being infinite has one other consequence:  For any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, only finitely many points can have probability $p \gt \varepsilon$.

Comment: I think the point is that part of the definition of probability space is countable additivity; thus, by definition, the probability of a countable union of disjoint sets is the sum of the probabilities. If you don't assume countable additivity, you don't get much of a theory.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thank you both!  If I could ask one final question though: is it not possible to have a space, say again $[0, 1] \cap \Bbb Q$, that is countable, yet infinite, where each element has the same probability?  This would then mean that the probability of any event is $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ as there are infinitely many rationals in the space (if this connects back to why you can't have a uniform distribution on the rationals then I'd be happy to independently research further).

Comment: If each rational has the same nonzero probability, then the space has infinite probability; if each rational has zero probability, then the whole space has zero probability; these are both nonsense, since, by definition, the whole space must have probability one. I have used countable additivity to reach these conclusions; again, that's part of the definition of a probability measure.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you again!